# How to add another field to a hash while importing a CSV file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, associations

I have a table with fields:

- location_cd
- dept_no
- acct_no
- amount
- s_dt
- fs_dt
- ccode

I need to import a CSV that only contains four fields: `dept_no`, `amount`, `acct_no`, `ccode`.

I am using a CSV.foreach loop to import. When the user selects the file to import before clicking the import button they will select a date for `s_dt`, and `fs_dt`.

While going through the loop it needs to add these selected dates to the `s_dt` field and the `fs_dt` field.

Also I have a second table that contains only 2 fields, `location_cd` and `ccode`. Within my loop I need to go through each row and update the `location_cd` in Table1 to be the same as Table2 `location_cd` where the `ccode` in Table2 matches the `ccode` in Table1.

In Table1 I have belongs_to :Table2 and in table2 I have has_many :Table1.

```
class Financial < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :financial_loc_ccode

    require 'csv'

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, row_sep: :auto, col_sep: "\t") do |row|
            financial_hash = row.to_hash
            location = FinancialLocCcode.where(ccode: financial_hash["ccode"])

            financial_hash[:location_cd] = location
            Financial.create!(financial_hash)
        end
    end
end
```

Here is my model, I get this error message

```
ERROR: value too long for type character varying(4) : INSERT INTO "financials" ("acct_no", "amount", "dept_no", "ccode", "location_cd") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id" (see image)
```

[image]

Also I have not the slightest clue where to begin to update `s_dt`, `fs_date`.

I am a beginner in rails and am way over my head. Any help would be much appreciated. If needed more information just let me know and I can provide more.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing looks to be telling you that the value you are trying to INSERT into the DB is too big/exceeds the limit of that the column.

From what I can see from the error you're getting, the data type on the column you're trying to set is [character varying(4)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html).  This means the length of the string you can INSERT into that column is 4 characters.

**A couple of things to try while debugging:**
**1.** Take a look at your database schema and figure out which column has those constraints -- that will give you a jumping off point.  You'll say, "OK, now I know which column is borking -- what am I trying to put in there?"

**2.** Run your code, line by line, in your [Rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html).  Inspect the INSERT statements and double check that the thing you're trying to stuff into the borking column, is indeed what you want to be putting in there.  If it is, consider if you need to change the constraints of the column.  If it isn't, well, don't put it in there!

**3.**  Do not be afraid of the `puts` statement, while debugging.  At every step in your loop, `puts financial_hash`.  Then run the loop in your console -- is your hash what you think it is?

I know I'm not giving you a ton of concrete advice besides "try debugging a little more" but hopefully this is a good jumping-off point.  Good luck!